# Tail production log with Capistrano - how to stop it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano

I found this nifty code snippet on several sites, allowing me to analyze the production log via Capistrano:

```
desc "tail production log files" 
task :tail_logs, :roles => :app do
  run "tail -f #{shared_path}/log/production.log" do |channel, stream, data|
    puts  # for an extra line break before the host name
    puts "#{channel[:host]}: #{data}" 
    break if stream == :err    
  end
end
```

It works perfectly well, however, when I'm finished reading the logs, I hit Ctrl+C and it produces a nasty error on my console. Not that this is a huge problem, but I find it annoying. What can I do so that no error is produced, but the task/tail/log viewing just quietly ends?

Also, I'm not that familiar with how to analyze logs - is this really the best way to just have a quick look at the most recent events in your (remote production) log, or is there a better way? I know there are a gazillion tools for log analysis, but I want a dead-simple solution to see the last couple requests, not something bulky and complicated. I'm not sure if this Capistrano solution is really optimal though. Like, what's the solution most people use?

Comment: We use log.io to tail our logs (especially during releases to watch unicorn reload). Not a log analysis tool but a great way to stream multiple logs at once. http://logio.org

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try `trap("INT") { puts 'Interupted'; exit 0; }` like this:

```
desc "tail production log files" 
task :tail_logs, :roles => :app do
  trap("INT") { puts 'Interupted'; exit 0; }
  run "tail -f #{shared_path}/log/production.log" do |channel, stream, data|
    puts  # for an extra line break before the host name
    puts "#{channel[:host]}: #{data}" 
    break if stream == :err
  end
end
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, precisely what I was looking for

Comment: This will not work if you interrupt before the tail start giving data. Putting the trap outside the block will prevent this

Answer (score 3):

This was pretty easy to find on [a blog](http://www.talkingquickly.co.uk/2013/12/tailing-log-files-with-capistrano-3/)

But here is some code for Capistrano 3

```
namespace :logs do
  desc "tail rails logs" 
  task :tail_rails do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute "tail -f #{shared_path}/log/#{fetch(:rails_env)}.log"
    end
  end
end
```

I had issues with the rails_env variable, so i just replaced it, but it might be worth it to you to get it working, so I left it.

Comment: I'm having some trouble making it work. The command runs fine but no output is showing. Any idea?

Comment: Check to make sure it's looking at the right file. You should be able to `puts` that same path, then SSH into your box, and be sure there is a log where it's looking. Also, just to be clear, as it's tailing, it may not show any content unless there is content added to the log at the time of looking.

Comment: You could also try hard coding the path to the log, where you know it is, just as a troubleshooting starting point.

Comment: The output is debug level. So you won't see any output if you have changed to log_level, :info for instance.

Answer (score 1):

I made one small change to Jeznet's great answer. If you run [capistrano-ext](https://github.com/neerajkumar/capistrano-ext) with multiple environments like we do, you can have the RAILS_ENV automatically specified for you:

```
run "tail -f #{shared_path}/log/#{rails_env}.log" do |channel, stream, data|
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with the trap("INT") part. While it makes the script exit without errors, the tail processes where still running on the remote machines. If fixed it with this line:

`trap("INT") { puts 'Interupted'; run "killall -u myusername tail"; exit 0; }`

Not elegant, but working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I use gem capistrano-rails-tail-log and everything is ok.
https://github.com/ayamomiji/capistrano-rails-tail-log